# Can't use IPv6 functionality in WinAPI IP helper with Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

I'm using the WinAPi IP helper in a C program to achieve a similar result to "netstat -nao".

My problem is that it doesn't load any of the IPv6 functionalities. Here are my includes :

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNING

#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <IPHlpApi.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

This what i found in a sample code at the Windows Dev Center

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309068(v=vs.85).aspx

I've also looked in the includes to be sure that the structures i'm looking for are there "PMIB_UDP6TABLE_OWNER_PID and PMIB_TCP6TABLE_OWNER_PID" and i've found them in udpmib.h and tcpmib.h which is included with the Iprtrmib.h included in IPHlpApi.h.

In those files the sections I'm trying to access are in wrapped in :

```
#ifdef _WS2IPDEF_
// Structures I desperately need
#endif
```

I've tried to use a #ifndef _WS2IPDEF in my header file, but it only corrected the problem for intellisense. Even then I need to "go to definition" for the error to go away and the program still won't compile.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: If you run into a compiler or linker error, it would help a lot, if you posted those error messages.

Comment: I have a lot of errors at compile time but they all refer to the structures i'm trying tu use. They are "undeclared identifier" for the variables and "identifier X is undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer after messing with the includes. The includes needed to be exactly in the order they were in the Windows Dev Center in order to work. The dependencies between the librairies needed to be resolved this way.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```